# change controller name convention in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, prefix

Is there a way to change the naming convention for controllers in ASP.NET MVC?

What I want is to name my controllers `InicioControlador` instead of `InicioController`, or better yet, use a prefix instead of a suffix, and have `ControladorInicio` as my controller name.

From what I have read so far, I think I have to implement my own Controller Factory. I would be very grateful if any of you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, ControllerFactory is the best solution of your problem.

```
public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {            
        BaseController controller;

        switch (controllerName.ToLower())
        {
            case "product": case "products": controller = new MyProductController(); break;
            case "home": controller = new MyHomeController(); break;
            case "account": controller = new MyAccountController(); break;
            default: controller = null; break;
        }

        return controller;
    }
```

This is my first ControllerFactory - but it is very stupid :) You must use reflection and avoid this ugly switch.

Answer (score 16):

I decided to dig a bit deeper and found exactly what I was looking for after searching through the MVC source code. The convention for controller names is deep inside the roots of the MVC Framework, especifically in two classes `ControllerDescriptor` and `ControllerTypeCache`.

In `ControllerDescriptor` it is given by the following attribute:

```
public virtual string ControllerName {
  get {
    string typeName = ControllerType.Name;
    if (typeName.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
      return typeName.Substring(0, typeName.Length - "Controller".Length);
    }
    return typeName;
  }
}
```

In `ControllerTypeCache` it is given by the following methods:

```
internal static bool IsControllerType(Type t) {
  return
    t != null &&
    t.IsPublic &&
    t.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
    !t.IsAbstract &&
    typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t);
}

public void EnsureInitialized(IBuildManager buildManager)
{
  if (_cache == null)
  {
    lock (_lockObj)
    {
      if (_cache == null)
      {
        List<Type> controllerTypes = TypeCacheUtil.GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies(_typeCacheName, IsControllerType, buildManager);
        var groupedByName = controllerTypes.GroupBy(
            t => t.Name.Substring(0, t.Name.Length - "Controller".Length),
            StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        _cache = groupedByName.ToDictionary(
            g => g.Key,
            g => g.ToLookup(t => t.Namespace ?? String.Empty, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
            StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
      }
    }
  }
```