# Can you change the ASP.NET MVC controller convention?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

By default asp.net mvc looks for controller classes that end with "Controller". Can I change it so that it looks for classes that end with underscore controller, "_Controller"?

Comment: So this apparently a dupe!  Your answer lies here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011482/controller-name-convention-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by creating your own [custom ControllerFactory](http://geekswithblogs.net/sankarsan/archive/2008/12/16/asp.net-mvc---developing-custom-controllerfactory.aspx).

Comment: ok so i can see that it is possible by writing my own controller factory. anybody have an example of a controller factory that gets controllers by class name convention other than the asp.net mvc default (something similar to what i'm doin).

Answer (score 0):

gideon is right, this is a dup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011482/change-controller-name-convention-in-asp-net-mvc) SO thread, see ControllerDescriptor & ControllerTypeCache. A better question is why do you feel the need to change it?