# asp.net mvc 5 Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-8, asp.net-mvc-5.2

i create sample project with asp.net mvc 5 and entity framework now when i want to run this project i encounter whit this error :

[image]

in my computer is installed .net 4.5 and 4.5.1 and my iis version is 8 too.

this my controller :

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using mvcWebApp01.Models;

namespace mvcWebApp01.Controllers
{
    public class HomeControllers : Controller
    {
        private DataBaseContext db = new DataBaseContext();

        // GET: HomeControllers
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.People.ToList());
        }

        // GET: HomeControllers/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Person person = db.People.Find(id);
            if (person == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(person);
        }

        // GET: HomeControllers/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: HomeControllers/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,FullName")] Person person)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.People.Add(person);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(person);
        }

        // GET: HomeControllers/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Person person = db.People.Find(id);
            if (person == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(person);
        }

        // POST: HomeControllers/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,FullName")] Person person)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(person);
        }

        // GET: HomeControllers/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Person person = db.People.Find(id);
            if (person == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(person);
        }

        // POST: HomeControllers/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Person person = db.People.Find(id);
            db.People.Remove(person);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `HomeControllers` to `HomeController`

Comment: Check the event viewer, it usually has more descriptive error messages than IIS

Comment: tanks so much @miparnisari you safe my life :)

Comment: You're welcome. I wrote an answer that expands on that coment.

Comment: saman please take a second and accept @miparnisari answer

Comment: I have removed `[solved]` from your title. If you want to mark a question as solved, click the checkmark next to an answer. Do not edit the word into your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET follows a "convention over configuration" approach. This means that, for instance, in order to instantiate your controllers, the default controller factory will try to look for classes following the naming convention `<Name>Controller`. If you don't like this approach you can write your own Controller Factory (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30581397/1623249) for example), but in general this is not necessary.

So to fix your problem you should rename `HomeControllers` to `HomeController`.