# Controller Class without Controller at the end of the name?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

For the reasons that are not important to the question, I would like to know how to make my controllers / routing work in ASP.NET MVC5 if my controller class names **do not end in** `Controller` as per convention? Do I need to manually register them somewhere?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011482/change-controller-name-convention-in-asp-net-mvc/30577420

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11557783/1529657

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Controller` suffix is baked into the the [`ControllerDescriptor`](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerDescriptor.cs#L19) and [`ControllerTypeCache`](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerTypeCache.cs#L86) classes making it hard to override. One way that comes to mind is to write a custom controller factory and override the [`GetControllerType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory.getcontrollertype(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerType(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext,System.String)) method.